# How to track anonymous email sender (alternatives to IP tracking)

Tags: email, forensics, email-spoofing, trojan

Are there any ways to get information on who is sending certain emails from an anonymous email address?

Besides the obvious IP solution, would there be any alternative such as embedding some kind of script or something that reads some phone information (such as phone name, carrier, etc...) when the receiver opens the email? Is there any software that could do something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You are talking about tracking an anonymous __sender__  but then you suddenly talk about something happening at the __receiver__ which might allow tracking. Do you imply (but not explicitly state) that one sends a mail back to the anonymous sender, so that sender will be receiver? But no, some generic mechanism like you envision does not exist. In some specific cases it _might_ be possible though to exploit security issues on the receiver side for this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich tracking pixels in the email would gather a lot of info.

Comment: @schroeder - While tracking pixels (originally known as Web Bugs) used to be a very common and effective mechanism years ago, I'm not aware of any modern email system this would work on short of intentionally misconfiguring it.